# Ignoring characters in a float array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am saving an excel file as .csv file which makes it have the style of:

```
58884,1,2912,3,,0,0,3_A,05-May-11,3,5,2,7.18161941,
```

so it makes all the columns separated by commas. When I read the array I have the data being put into a float array. How can I separate the commas from the numbers I really want? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Reconlll , You can edit your question to correct typos and everything. You'll get better responses if you add what you have tried, your code, etc

Comment: @ReconIII what numbers you **really want**, there are a lot of numbers.

Comment: and a couple of things that aren't numbers at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I suggest the following 2 steps:

1. Split the arrays by commas
2. Check if every part splited is an number, if yes, add it to the array.

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c) a good solution about how to split the string.
For checking if the string obtained is a valid number see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78474/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-or-a-float-in-ansi-c).